# SQL subquery to pull gallons for last 6 months from the respective date

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a need to pull deals by date, location and customer and gallons for last 6 months from the respective date.
I am using IBM Netezza DB.

My code:

```
SELECT 
    DT.DIM_DATE_ID, DT.LOCATION_ID, DT.CUSTOMER, DT.DEAL, GL.GALLONS
FROM 
    DEALS_TBL DT 
JOIN 
    DIM_DATE D ON D.DIM_DATE_ID = DT.DIM_DATE_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         D.MONTH, D.DIM_DATE_ID, D.DATE_ID, 
         G.LOCATION_ID, G.CUSTOMER, G.QUANTITY, 
         SUM(G.QUANTITY) OVER (ORDER BY D.DATE_ID, G.LOCATION_ID, G.CUSTOMER) GALLONS
     FROM 
         FCT_GALLON G 
     JOIN 
         DIM_DATE D ON D.DIM_DATE_ID = G.DIM_DATE_ID
     WHERE 
         D.DATE_ID BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(D.DATE_ID, -6) AND D.DATE_ID) GL ON GL.DIM_DATE_ID = DT.DIM_DATE_ID 
                            AND GL.LOCATION_ID = DT.LOCATION_ID 
                            AND GL.CUSTOMER = DT.CUSTOMER
WHERE 
    D.DATE_ID = '2020-11-08'
```

For example if I am pulling the deal data for '2020-11-08' date I would wish to pull the sum of gallons from '2020-05-08' to '2020-11-08'
I am failing to do that with above left joined sub query.

Please refer to the sample data below and the expected output where the gallon is sum of QUANTITY from FCT_GALLON table from 20200508 to 20201108.

[image: DEALS_TBL]

[image: DIM_DATE]

[image: FCT_GALLON]

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: To a close approximation, no one else knows what your data looks like, nor what the desired results are.  You can provide such information in your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff hope the example above helps :)

Answer (score 1):

can you try this?

```
select 
     de.DIM_DATE_ID, 
     de.LOCATION_ID, de.CUSTOMER, 
     sum(fc.QUANTITY) from DEALS_TBL de
left join DIM_DATE di 
    on di.DIM_DATE_ID=de.DIM_DATE_ID 
left join FCT_GALLON fc 
    on fc.CUSTOMER = de.CUSTOMER and fc.LOCATION_ID = de.LOCATION_ID 
where
  di.DATE_ID= '2021-03-01' and fc.DIM_DATE_ID between add_months(de.DIM_DATE_ID, -6) and de.DIM_DATE_ID 
   group by DE.DIM_DATE_ID,DE.LOCATION_ID, DE.CUSTOMER;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This isn't returning the expected result.... Its failing to apply the 6 month filter while bringing the sum of gallons.